# how to avoid "The local variable mMap may not have been initialized"

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm building an application in which I have to get the map at zoom level.
here is the code:

```
 public class MapView extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

            GoogleMap mMap;
            float zoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        }
    }
```

but it is giving an error "The local variable mMap may not have been initialized" at mMap variable and when I put mMap = null; the application is crashed and said "Unfortunately, the MapView has stopped" How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GoogleMap object is null. You cannot instantiate a GoogleMap object directly, rather, you must obtain one from the getMap() method on a MapFragment or MapView that you have added to your application, according to the official docs.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)

Comment: sorry I am a newbie so I don't understand by the term non-null value. If object is not equal to null then what it should be?

Comment: Check my edit. You should check the links first,pal.